# Componentes Visuales en PHP

Tags: php, aplicación-web

Estoy en la fase inicial de un proyecto web en PHP y necesito saber que librerías o frameworks puedo usar para dar formato a mi web. Me explico mejor en ASP pudiera usar silverlight o devexpress que son componentes visuales cual seria su equivalente en PHP??

Comment: PHP no tiene esas bondades porque no está orientado a componentes como ASP.NET. En su lugar, puedes utilizar componentes HTML 5 o componentes creados por librerías JavaScript + CSS como jQuery Table o similares.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta luiggi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP no tiene esas "bondades" porque no está orientado a componentes como ASP.NET. En su lugar, puedes utilizar componentes HTML 5 o componentes creados por librerías JavaScript + CSS como jQuery Table o similares.